# How to pass data from one widget to a non widget using Valuenotifier?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Currently, I can pass data from one widget to another using `ValueNotifier` and  `ValueListenableBuilder` but it always has a child property , what If I just need the data and not build a child how can I do this ?

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  TextEditingController textEditingController = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
          SizedBox(
            height: 30,
            child: Center(
              child: Text("widget 1"),
            ),
          ),
          TextField(
            controller: textEditingController,
            // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Enter Value',
              // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
            ),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              BottomBar.enteredValue.value = textEditingController.text;
            },
            child: const Text('Send data'),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 30),
          BottomBar()
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BottomBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const BottomBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static ValueNotifier<String> enteredValue = ValueNotifier('');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 200,
      // ignore: prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables
      child: Column(
        // ignore: prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables
        children: [
          Text('Widget 2'),
          SizedBox(
            height: 40,
          ),
          ValueListenableBuilder(
            valueListenable: enteredValue,
            builder: (context, String value, child) {
              return Text(value);
            },
          ),
           //    FirebaseDatabase(databaseURL: firebaseUrl)
           // .reference()
           // .child(enteredValue);
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here in the above `BottomPage` I just need `enteredValue` to update my firebase, I don't need the text I am adding it there because the `ValueListenableBuilder` requires a child property

```
FirebaseDatabase(databaseURL: firebaseUrl)
    .reference()
    .child(enteredValue);
```

How can I do this from `ValueListenable` or how do I pass it thru constructor? which is a better method ? I don't want to use `Provider` .

Comment: `ValueListenable` extends `Listenable` class so check all the methods [Listenable](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/Listenable-class.html) class offers

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: `enteredValue.addListener(listener)`